# android - how to parse json from file in SDCard

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, fileinputstream

hi i want to parse my downloaded json file that stored in the SDCard directory ,

i don't know how can i do that !

im google a lot but i can only find somethings like : BuffredReader , InputFileStream , ...

please help me !

here is part of my code but it have the problem i attached in the image :

```
File GroupsJsonFileAdress = new File(Enviroments.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FOLDER/G.json");

try {
        ObjectInputStream groupsInJson = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(GroupsJsonFileAdress));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)groupsInJson.readObject();
        String DATABASE_VERSION = jsonObject.getString("DBVersion");
        JSONArray groupsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Groups");
        for (int i = 0; i < groupsArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject groupJsonObjectReader = groupsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id= groupJsonObjectReader.getInt("Id");
            String gTitle = groupJsonObjectReader.getString("title");
            Group loaderG = new Group();
            loaderG.GroupId = id;
            loaderG.Title = gTitle;
            Log.i("INFO", loaderG.Title);
            groupsClasses.add(loaderG);
        }
    } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is the error i got :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ3YN.jpg

Comment: don't use an `ObjectInputStream` it doesn't make any sense in your situation. Read a String and then parse it, or use a JsonStreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

Create a model that matches your Json architecture and then parse it using GSON librarie ;)
Easiest way to do it so far for me :)